# App crashes in simulator when I add SKAudioNode?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

Ok so the app loads the initial MenuScene fine but as soon as I want to transfer over to the GameScene on the simulator, the game crashes and it gives me "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

From commenting some stuff out and seeing if it still ran, I was able to figure out that the only thing causing the app to crash was adding SKAudioNodes to the scene.

I've tested it on my actual device and it works fine though. Is it a problem with my code? Or is it a problem with the simulator?

The console prints out a bunch of stuff that I can't really decipher. This is just some of it.

> [aqme] 318: error -66680 finding/initializing AQDefaultDevice
> 80: Failed to set processVolumeScalar on device. Error: 560947818
> AudioHAL_Client] AudioHardware.cpp:2692:AudioDeviceStop:  AudioDeviceStop: no device with given ID
> AudioHardware.cpp:780:AudioObjectSetPropertyData:  AudioObjectSetPropertyData: no object with given ID 0
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
let bg: SKAudioNode = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "background.mp3")
    let fuse = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "fuse.wav")


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        if soundIsOn {
            self.addChild(bg)
            self.addChild(fuse)
        }
}

}
```

Edit:
After further investigation, I've determined that the line of code causing the error is the line where I add the child "fuse"

Comment: Simulator doesn't supports audio input frameworks. Test it in real device.

Comment: @manishsharma93 yes it does.   Alicia Natividad, post some code.  I have a feeling you are adding the audio node before the audio engine is initialized

Comment: You may have misspelled a variable. That may the cause. Also, check which line of code is causing the NSException by adding Exception breakpoints. You'll get to know immediately. You haven't initialized the audio player.

Comment: @ojassethi No and No.  A misspelled variable would lead to the compiler breaking, and `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`is for using the `AVAudioPlayer,` not `SKAudioNode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that your audio engine is not initialized yet (nothing you can do, this is all on Apple) so.....

Try

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    let bg: SKAudioNode = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "background.mp3")
    let fuse = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "fuse.wav")


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            [weak self]
            guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
            if soundIsOn {
                strongSelf.addChild(bg)
                strongSelf.addChild(fuse)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    let bg: SKAudioNode = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "background.mp3")
    let fuse = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "fuse.wav")


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            [weak self]
            guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
            if soundIsOn {
                strongSelf.addChild(bg)
                strongSelf.addChild(fuse)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know which one of these worked if any.  Preferably, we want the 1st one working, but if the second one works only, then we need to find a better spot for you to add your audio nodes.